# Are these market prices balanced for these abilities?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons

Energy Charging:
After spending 3 hours under the sunlight, this weapon begins glowing. You can spend this charged energy and cause 2d6 extra fire damage.

Shadow Regeneration:
When in total darkness, you regain 2d6 HP at the start of every round only when wounded, and it stacks with other regeneration forms like Fast Healing. Every time this happens to a creature that doesn't have the Demon subtype, there is a chance of 25% that it will undergo one of 7 stages of transformation into a Shadow Demon. From the 4th stage onwards, you will gain a second personality that will grow in strength as the stages continue, eventually taking full control at the 7th stage. This effect is completely irreversible without the use of a Wish or Miracle and will have a visible effect.

Shatterer:
when used to break equipment treat this weapon as if it had a +5 enhancement bonus, applying the corresponding bonus to attack and damage.

I would place Energy Charging as a +1 enhancement bonus, and Shadow Regeneration and Shatterer as +2. Would this be balanced, or am I overlooking something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for Energy Charging seems much demanding to me: for the same enhancement bonus I'd go for a Fire weapon (+1d6 fire with each strike). I'd go for a constant +500 gp to the total price.

Comment: Is Shadow Regeneration activated each round? At the start or at the end? Is cumulative with other regeneration forms? Does it trigger the check if the wielder is at full hp? +2 seems to low to me (players could be creative and sure can find many ways to gain the Demon subtype).

Comment: About the Shatterer quality... it seems fair to be gauged on a +2, probably a bit under-powered (but I think a +1 could be too low). The fact that it must be applied to an at least +1 weapon gives it a virtual +4 bonus only against equipment. Useful but very circumstantial (especially in the hands of greedy PCs).

Comment: Hey, @Erik, turn those three comments into an answer :)

Comment: @ErikBurigo: The Shatterer quality is, as you say, very circumstancial, but is quite handy when combined with [a certain weapon](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12604/how-do-i-price-a-sword-that-absorbs-other-weapons-abilities)...

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton. It was my first thought, but one of them started as a request for obtaining more details, while I didn't feel comfortable in posting the other 2 as answers :P (I've lost my grasp on 3.5 pricing and my rage drake ate my homework -_-')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**

3 hours for a 2d6 charge is a flat price increase or, more accurately, a complete waste of time.

<strike>Shadow regen is missing a unit time. It's also a curse. Why would anyone want this? It turns you into a demon in 7/.25 units time. If the unit time is in rounds, then it's fast healing 2d6 and completely cursed. If it's in minutes, it... may be worth a +2 to a demon who doesn't already have healing from some source.</strike> From the perspective of a demon, 2d6 fast heal is 7 fast heal, I'd say that a sword that does that is easily in the +4/+5 category.

The test for this is to ask "would I rather have X or shadow regen" if the answer is a clear decision in either direction, the item isn't balanced. Given that I'd rather have this than vorpal, dancing, or brilliant energy, it is at least a +5 (and only that because of the curse on normal PCs holding it that will turn into demons in about 3 minutes.

<strike>Shatterer is the... shatter ability used on hit. Should be flat priced according to the custom magic item table.</strike> For the shatterer ability as written... I would rather have all the listed +2 abilities than it, making it +1.

Comment: You're right, EC should have a flat increase, probably 500 gp like Erik says. About Shadow regen, see the edit. As for why anyone would want it... you're assuming it's a human that wants it.  I'm not sure what you mean by the "shatter ability". If you mean the Shatter spell, then it does nothing like that, it adds an enhancement bonus that can overcome DR and adds attack and damage.

Comment: Edited. New comments?

Comment: I think that yes, Shadow Regen is a powerful quality for a Demon, but very dangerous for everyone else, so I consider it tricky. As for Shattering, Sundering is a +1 quality and it's worse than this. Maybe I could make it a synergy with Sundering?

Comment: Yes, one of the later DMGs had "upgrade" magic item powers that stacked, though I forget which one. This would be an excellent sundering upgrade.